# DB Replication is failing with "The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' " error

Tags: database-replication

I am troubleshooting an issue with DB replication on SQL Server 2017. The log reader agent is using a domain account and it is the db_owner of the databases. But still, I am seeing the following error in the replication monitor

The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' on 'mydb'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007)
Get help: http://help/1007
Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform this operation. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007)
Get help: http://help/1007
Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform this operation.Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform this operation. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007)
Get help: http://help/1007

Comment: Just another note. 

If I dropped all subscriptions, the publisher statuses will show as OK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually with the LogReader account. It just needs to have sysadmin privilege to be added in the DB login.